# On Scribblenauts Remix level 4-3, how do I get the psychologist/psychiatrist to enter the cell?

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

On level 4-3 of *Scribblenauts Remix*, you need to get all the cells open by causing the specialists to enter them.  Three are easy, but the fourth cell, which has a Psychiatrist outside, is just baffling me.

There's actually an in-game hint that says "The Pyschiatrist will calm a panicked prisoner" but no matter what potions I apply to my prisoner (like "insane" or "depressed" or "panicky") the dude ignores him.

Trying to literally make a "panicked potion" doesn't work, giving me a plain potion.

How in the word do I get this psychiatrist's attention?!

P.S. Giving the prisoner a "suicidal potion" will just kill him, heh.

[image]

Comment: Reading this question is making me want to play Scribblenauts again...what have you done?

Comment: @Strix: I have 4 Words for you: Tiny Polite Polkadot Cthulu. http://i.imgur.com/GRxSV.jpg Why yes, that *is* a top hat and monocle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a zombie in the room with the prisoner.

Comment: Thaaank you.  Got stuck on potions and didn't think of just trying to scare him.

Comment: I never used potions playing through the DS version, personally.

Comment: Just be careful not to use zombie as an adjective (eg "zombie turtle") as it will attack the prisoner and psychiatrist and turn them into zombies, and you lose the level!

Answer (score 3):

You can also put mother in there

Comment: Yea, i typed 'the psychiatrist mother" and put her beside the prisoner and surprisingly it really works.

Answer (score 3):

I put a scary chair in the cell!

Answer (score 2):

I totally didn't get that he was a psychiatrist. I thought (from the appearance) that it was Einstein.  "That seems a bit bizarre," I told myself, "but then I spent the last hour carrying a medusa head chained to a stick and riding around on a giant winged metal firebreathing manic depressive acrophobic cthulu which was wearing a polkadot fedora and toting a railgun, so who am I to judge."

Anyway, I dropped a wormhole in the room (singularity kills the prisoner). After a few seconds a demon popped out - Tada!  Panicky prisoner.